# HttpClient Error 505 Phisical Device IOS Not Working

Tags: ios, json, http, xamarin, httpclient

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://212.212.212.212/Test/");
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage json = await client.PostAsync(method , content);
        json.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var response =await json.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

It works on ios emulator. However, when I install the application on a real device, http/1.1 does not supported error 505. Could I be getting this error because https is not available?

Comment: I found. NSUrlSession selected for Ios Simulator must be selected in Iphone. I forgot to select it in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is the exact opposite. iOS blocks by default every non-secure endpoint, therefore all "http" connection (not https).

There are a couple of ways around this using [App Transport Security in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats).

The easiest way is simply to allow all http traffic through the app; adding this to your iOS solution's .plist. However I would not necessarily recommend this extreme solution.

```
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

However the recommended way, would be to specificly allow only certain endpoint to be accessible. Again through your plist, you can include them like this:

```
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
       <key>subdomain.somedomain.com</key>
       <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key><true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key><true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key><false/>
       </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thansk for reply